# invalid index 0 ,size is 0 for RSS FEED

Tags: android, rss

I am trying to put a RSS FEED of weather && psi into my application.
They are from yahoo weather and nea.gov.sg respectively.

However, when I run the application, I get a force close error. After looking at the logcat, it was shown that invalid index 0, size is 0. Can someone tell me what's wrong with the error and how could I solve it?
I'm trying out on using the rss feed.

LOGCAT

```
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fuellogproject/com.example.fuellogproject.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at com.example.fuellogproject.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:135)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
02-20 22:11:50.906: E/AndroidRuntime(12108):    ... 11 more
```

CODE

```
  public class HomeActivity extends Activity{

    Button btnLogIn;

    Button btnExit;
    TextView name;
    final Context context = this;
    Session session;


    //WEATHERVAR
    ArrayList<String> psi;

      public TextView psi_text;

    TextView weather;
     ImageView image;
     private static Handler mHandler = new Handler();
     class MyWeather{


      String conditiontext;
      String conditiontemp;
      String conditiondate;



      public String forecastToString(){

       return 
               "        "  +  conditiontemp + "°C" ;

      } 
     }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);
         weather = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weather);
            image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
            psi = new ArrayList<String>();  
            psi_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.psi_text);
         session = new Session(getApplicationContext());
         session.checkLogin();
       Log.i("HomeActivity.java", "User login status: " +  session.isLoggedIn());
         name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);        
         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

         HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
         String username = user.get(Session.KEY_NAME);
         name.setText(username);
         btnLogIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogIn);
            btnExit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonExit);
            btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    finish();
                }
            });

            try {

                URL url = new URL(
                        "http://app2.nea.gov.sg/data/rss/nea_psi.xml");
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                    Node node = nodeList.item(i);       

                    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;                 

                    NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("psi");
                    Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                    websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();

                    psi.add(""+ ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());           

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
            }



            String temp = Html.fromHtml(psi.get(0)).toString(); 
            String a[] = temp.split("\\)");
            psi_text.setText(""+a[0]+")");


            Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                 @Override
                   public void run() {
                    String weatherString = QueryYahooWeather();
                          Document weatherDoc = convertStringToDocument(weatherString);

                          final MyWeather weatherResult = parseWeather(weatherDoc);
                          runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                              @Override
                                 public void run() {
                                  weather.setText(weatherResult.forecastToString());
                                 }});

                               }});
                                    myThread.start();
                                }




  public void CheckUser(View v)

    {
          Intent intentAbout=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
          startActivity(intentAbout);
    }


  protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {

        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
    }

    private MyWeather parseWeather(Document srcDoc){

         MyWeather myWeather = new MyWeather();

            //<yweather:condition.../>
         Node conditionNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0);


         String weatherCode = conditionNode.getAttributes()
               .getNamedItem("code")
               .getNodeValue()
               .toString();

         // thunderstorms
         if(weatherCode.equals("4")){

             mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This gets executed on the UI thread so it can safely modify
                    // Views

                     image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                }
            });
         }

         //isolated thunderstorms
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("37")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                        }
                    });
                }


         //scattered thunderstorms
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("38")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                        }
                    });
                }

         //scattered thunderstorms
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("39")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                        }
                    });
                }

         //thundershowers
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("45")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                        }
                    });
                }

         //isolated thundershowers
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("47")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                        }
                    });
                }

         //drizzle
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("9")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rainy);
                        }
                    });
                }

         //showers
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("11")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rainy);
                        }
                    });
                }

//showers
else if ( weatherCode.equals("12")) {
 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {

         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rainy);
     }
 });
}

         //scattered showers
else if ( weatherCode.equals("40")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rainy);
            }
        });
    }

         //hail
else if ( weatherCode.equals("17")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hail);
            }
        });
    }


         //mixed rain and hail
else if ( weatherCode.equals("35")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hail);
            }
        });
    }

         //foggy
else if ( weatherCode.equals("20")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.foggy);
            }
        });
    }

         //haze
else if ( weatherCode.equals("21")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.foggy);
            }
        });
    }

         //smoky
else if ( weatherCode.equals("22")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.foggy);
            }
        });
    }

         //windy
else if ( weatherCode.equals("24")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.windy);
            }
        });
    }

         //cloudy
else if ( weatherCode.equals("26")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //fair (night)
else if ( weatherCode.equals("33")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //fair (day)
else if ( weatherCode.equals("34")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //partly cloudy
else if ( weatherCode.equals("44")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //mostly cloudy (night)
else if ( weatherCode.equals("27")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.night_cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //partly cloudy (night)
else if ( weatherCode.equals("29")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.night_cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //mostly cloudy (day)
else if ( weatherCode.equals("28")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_cloudy);
            }
        });
    }


         //partly cloudy (day)
    else if ( weatherCode.equals("30")) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_cloudy);
                }
            });
        }




         //clear(night)
    else if ( weatherCode.equals("31")) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.moon);
                }
            });
        }


         //sunny
    else {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sunny);
                }
            });
        }




         myWeather.conditiontext = conditionNode.getAttributes()
    .getNamedItem("text")
    .getNodeValue()
    .toString();

         myWeather.conditiontemp = conditionNode.getAttributes()
                   .getNamedItem("temp")
                   .getNodeValue()
                   .toString();




  return myWeather; 
 }

 private Document convertStringToDocument(String src){

  Document dest = null;
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder parser;

  try {
   parser = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   dest = parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(src.getBytes())); 
  } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,
     e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
  } catch (SAXException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,
     e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,
     e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
  }

  return dest; 
 }

 private String QueryYahooWeather(){

  String qResult = "";
  String queryString = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=1062617&u=c";

  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(queryString);

  try {
   HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();

   if (httpEntity != null){
    InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
    Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(in);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    String stringReadLine = null;

    while ((stringReadLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
     stringBuilder.append(stringReadLine + "\n"); 
    }

    qResult = stringBuilder.toString(); 
   } 
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,
     e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,
     e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
  }

  return qResult; 
 }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 135, you should check if `psi.get(0)` is null. Maybe try implementing it as this:

```
if (psi.get(0).length() != 0){
   String temp = Html.fromHtml(psi.get(0)).toString(); 
} else {
   String temp = "";}
```